# Random quote generator displays multiple quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, generator, quote

I need to make a random quote generator that displays multiple quotes in a range from 1 to 10 depending on what a user inputs on a form.  I call the function onsubmit = "generate()" in an HTML file.  I have the following so far in a js file:

```
var quotes = [
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me",
  "This is a sample quote. - me"
 ];


function generate() {
  var number = document.getElementById('numInput').value;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
   document.getElementById('goodQuotes').innerHTML = number[random];

 }
```

If a user enters any number between 1 and 10, I need to display that many quotes on the page.  Any help would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: You want `quotes[random]`. And you want to use a loop with that `number`

Comment: *"If a **user enters any number** between 1 and 10, I need to display that many quotes on the page. "* So what's random about that?